# Which Authorize.net API & docs do I use for Person Present / EMV payments

Tags: authorize.net

From looking at the [API Reference](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html) I can not find docs that cover the the use of Authorize.net iOS SDK and EMV [card readers](https://partner.posportal.com/authorizenet/auth/) to integrate a POS solution to take person present payments.

Can anyone direct em to the correct docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Card-present, in-person Authorize.Net IOS SDK as well as some documentation is located at: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/inperson-sdk-ios/

Comment: thanks. Is this still official/supported by Authorize.net? I am concerned as I dont see it on their website?